# How to set up multiple schema in django with oracle as a database?

Tags: python, django, database, oracle, schema

My workplace is planning to use Python/Django as a backend framework and React on the front, on top of oracle db from ASP classic. Since our oracle db structured from the beginning of the company, we decided to keep it as is.

From my understanding, schemas in oracle are typically accessed by username/password, thus need to have user/password for each schema to have an access and our oracle db has about 30ish schemas, containing numerous tables inside for each.

Django, on the other hand, seems it only supports one schema at a time, based on app that is installed in settings.py, which sounds like the databases configuration need to have different user/password set up in settings.py for each app installed.

So far, I've tried `class Meta` and `DATABASES` in `settings.py`;

```
    // class Meta
    class SomeModel(models.Model):
            ///some fields and data types...

            class Meta():
                    managed=False
                    db_table=u'"schema\".\"table"'

    // DATABASES
    DATABASES = {
          'default': {
                'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.oracle',
                'NAME': 'multi_schema_db',
                'USER': 'django_user',
                'PASSWORD': 'secret',
          },

          'data': {
                'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.oracle',
                'NAME': 'multi_schema_db',
                'USER': 'data_user',
                'PASSWORD': 'secret',
          },
    }
```

My questions is, is there any workaround to have an access into multiple schema where django has only one app installed?

P.S. Correct me on any misunderstandings that I have above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[You can have multiple schemas in Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/multi-db/#defining-your-databases)

```
DATABASES = {
      'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.oracle',
            'NAME': 'multi_schema_db_1',  # The name is the schema
            'USER': 'django_user',
            'PASSWORD': 'secret',
      },

      'data': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.oracle',
            'NAME': 'multi_schema_db_2',  # The name is the schema
            'USER': 'data_user',
            'PASSWORD': 'secret',
      },
}
```

To use a particular schema you use [.using()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/multi-db/#manually-selecting-a-database-for-a-queryset)

```
SomeModel.objects.using('data').all()  # The default is to use the "default" database conection
```

If some models are only ever in one schema you can use [routers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/multi-db/#using-routers) to define which database to use for each model

```
class YourRouter:

    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        return database_for_the_model

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        return database_for_the_model
```